# Mysql compare values in table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following query in order to compare values from two tables. SUM(u.val) is the value of total payments and I want to compare that value with the value of the invoice (r.p_val) and get listed only those with a lower value od SUM.

```
SELECT u.nmb, SUM(u.val) AS total_val,r.p_val
FROM inv u
INNER JOIN bills r ON r.nmb = u.nmb
WHERE total_val < r.p_val  
GROUP BY u.nmb
```

With this query I get error "Unknown column 'total_val' in 'where clause'"

I only managed to get a result with a query that compares the individual values and not the total payment. That query looks like this:

```
 SELECT u.nmb, u.val, SUM(u.val) AS total_val,r.p_val
 FROM inv u
 INNER JOIN bills r ON r.nmb = u.nmb
 WHERE  u.val < r.p_val  
 GROUP BY u.nmb
```

Is there a way to do some similar query and get the required result?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change WHERE to HAVING. WHERE does not have access to columns defined in the select list nor to GROUP BY aggregations:

```
SELECT u.nmb, SUM(u.val) AS total_val,r.p_val
FROM inv u
INNER JOIN bills r ON r.nmb = u.nmb
GROUP BY u.nmb
HAVING SUM(u.val) < r.p_val
```

Comment: Thanks. This query does exactly what I need. If I want to get listed and those invoices without any payment (records) in table "inv", how can I do that?

Comment: Change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN

Comment: I tried this but query with LEFT JOIN  only works if there is record in the table "inv" for the invoice. Without records for that invoice it will not list the invoice.

Comment: In this case - use RIGTH JOIN or OUTER JOIN. LEFT returns all records from inv regardless of existents of bills, RIGHT returns all from bills regardless of existents of invs and OUTER shows all from inv and bills.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.nmb, SUM(u.val) AS total_val,r.p_val
FROM inv u
INNER JOIN bills r ON r.nmb = u.nmb  
GROUP BY u.nmb
HAVING total_val < r.p_val
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a column alias in the WHERE clause.  Replace total_val with SUM(u.val) in the original query and it should work.